# Selecting/caching on one database connection, writing cached results to another

Tags: php, mysql, caching, mysqli

I have a query running on mysql workbench that runs on a separate connection from our production server, but it's read only. the best thing I can do is select what I need adn then insert it into another SCHEMA on the connection, but the user overall is read only.

So, I need to find a way to cache select results in one db connection and then write them to a table on another database connection.

Another option that we would potentially like to take is to have a php script run on our production server that would be set through windows task scheduler to run every 15 minutes and connect to db1, select results, connect to db2 and insert results. However, I'm not sure if this php script looks 100% right, because I've only ever done this with one db connection in php. When I use powershell to change directories and type `php 'filename.php'` I get a mysqli error on line 12.

```
        <?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";

    $servername2 = "localhost";
    $username2 = "user2";
    $password2 = "pass2";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    $conn2 = new mysqli($servername2, $username2, $password2);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";

    // Check connection2
    if ($conn2->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn2->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";

    $data = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT c.extension
                                      ,RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID
                                      , sum(Duration)
                                      , round(sum(Duration) / 60,2)
                                      , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0))
                                      , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0))
                                      , sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1))
                                      , count(DISTINCT b.NOTABLECALLID)
                                      , NOW()
                                      , curdate()
                                  FROM cdrdb.session a
                                  LEFT JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
                                       ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
                                  LEFT join cdrdb.mxuser c
                                       ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
                                  WHERE b.ts >= curdate()
                                  AND c.extension IN (7295,7306,7218,7247,7330,7000,7358)
                                  group by c.extension");

    foreach ($data as $d) {

    mysqli_query($conn2, "Insert into test.ambition_test(Extension, ExtID, Total_Talk_Time_seconds,
                          Total_Talk_Time_minutes,Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound,
                          Missed_Calls, Total_Calls, Time_of_report,Date_of_report  )
                            ON duplicate key update Total_Talk_Time_seconds = values('".$d['Total_Talk_Time_seconds']."'), Total_Talk_Time_minutes = values('".$d['Total_Talk_Time_minutes']."'), Total_Outbound =
                            values('".$d['Total_Outbound']."'), Total_Inbound =
                            values('".$d['Total_Inbound']."'), Missed_calls =
                            values('".$d['Missed_Calls']."'), Total_Calls =
                            values('".$d['Total_Calls']."'), Time_of_report =
                            NOW()");
    }

     ?>
```

To be sure, would that file keep localhost for both server names or would I put my mysql db connection IP addresses there?

Comment: `$servername` should be the server you're connecting to. Where is the database in relation to the server that will be executing the PHP? If it's the same machine for either database, then 'localhost' would be fine, otherwise you need to know the server's name or address and use the correct credentials for each. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes that does answer that question. i'll update the code and try that. The only other thing I was asking outside of that was how I could, in mysql workbench, cache the results from the read in order to write to another conenction

Comment: MySQL workbench is of no use. Use those credentials to connect to the database, execute your query in PHP and then write those results to the database in your other connection. Once you fetch the results from the server, they're stored in a PHP array or object until the end of the scripts execution.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that again then. So, my code for the data objects looks correct for the array though?

Comment: I honestly didn't read through with a fine tooth comb, just took a glance and read your question. I'd suggest giving it a try, and if (when, no offense - everything takes trial and error) it fails, looks at the error message or log to see where the issue is. But in concept, I think you're in the right direction already

Comment: Awesome, will do. Thank you